# How use C++ regex define Javascript function call pattern

Tags: c++, regex

I am try to use std::regex to search function call pattern on Javascript code,
but I have some problem.

My target is "`identifier()`" pattern, but definition pattern contain call pattern.

I am use negative lookahead to define not contain pattern(like `if()、` `for()、` `while())`, but lookahead can't use whitespace.

How define not contain "`function identifier()`", but have to contain "`identifier()`" pattern.

C++ can not use lookbehind on [regex](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/ECMAScript/)

```
    //This is my current pattern
    (?!if|while|for|switch|function)\b\w+(?=\s*\()\([^\)]*\)

    //function definition pattern
    function identifier()
    {...}

    //function call pattern
    identidier();
```

Comment: I think you might be better off using a real parser like [`boost::spirit::qi`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi.html) instead of a regex.

Comment: `var s = "not_a_function_call()"; but_this_is /* pickle surprise! */ ( );`

Comment: Dear NathanOliver: I know boost.regex library, but it's performance not better.

Comment: Dear  melpomene: I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: He means that it's not that easy to parse a language with regex helps and that boost has a create parser that you should use instead